# Hasse-Weil bound for even degree polynomial

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

Consider the equation $y^2 = f(x)$, in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$($q$ is a prime power) where $f(\cdot)$ is a monic polynoimal of even degree (greater than or equal to $4$) with integer coefficients. Let $N_f$ be the number of solutions of the above equation in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Is it true that $|N_f - q| \le C_f \sqrt{q}$, for some constant $C_f$?

Comment: You don't care whether $f$ is irreducible??  What if $f(x) = x^4$?